# How does react-native-measure-text calculate height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-text

I want to measure the `height` of a text component in `react-native` without laying it out on screen.

`react-native-measure-text` can be used for this, but how does this library calculates it.

Comment: Checkout the source code. The function is different for Android and iOS https://github.com/airamrguez/react-native-measure-text/blob/master/android/src/main/java/io/github/airamrguez/RNMeasureTextModule.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a Text component with the same properties as the one you want to measure, and then sets the *onLayout* prop to a function that captures the layout information of the Text component when it is rendered. The layout information includes the height and width of the component, which can be used to calculate the height of the text.
After rendering the Text component with *onLayout*, react-native-measure-text removes the component from the screen, but retains its layout information. It then returns the height of the component to you, allowing you to measure the height of the original text component without actually rendering it on the screen.